# Devise routing error: No route matches [PUT]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to get all my devise routes to be the way I want them to be:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'join' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
    post 'join' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
    get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    get 'account_settings' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => :edit_user_registration
    put 'account_settings' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => :update_user_registration
    get 'forgot_password' => 'devise/passwords#new', :as => :new_user_password
    get 'user', :to => 'user_pages#home', :as => :user_root
  end

  match '/user' => 'user_pages#home', :as => :user_root
```

When I go to the the Account settings (or Devise edit registration) and try to update it. I get the error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [PUT] "/join"
```

It suppose to go back to the home page. Why would I get this error? How do I fix it?

**EDIT**

Here's all of the Devise routes and the ones I made:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               registrations#destroy
   new_user_registration GET    /join(.:format)                devise/registrations#new
       user_registration POST   /join(.:format)                devise/registrations#create
        new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /login(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /logout(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
  edit_user_registration GET    /account_settings(.:format)    devise/registrations#edit
       new_user_password GET    /forgot_password(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
```

It's hard for me to look at this and see what I need to change. So if anyone knows it would help greatly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the one line change, i am writing here full code:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'join' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
    put 'join' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
    get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    get 'account_settings' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => :edit_user_registration
    put 'account_settings' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => :update_user_registration
    get 'forgot_password' => 'devise/passwords#new', :as => :new_user_password
    get 'user', :to => 'user_pages#home', :as => :user_root
  end

  match '/user' => 'user_pages#home', :as => :user_root
```

In above i've changed line

```
post 'join' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
```

to

```
put 'join' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
```

or make your request **post** request.

Comment: After submitting new registration, this happens: `No route matches [POST] "/join"`

Comment: I turned the `post` to `put` like you just did.

Comment: Then why your request changed from put to post? Can you provide your html code.

Comment: The form is `post` and I did as you did here: `put 'join' => 'devi......`. `<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/join" class="new_user" id="join-form" method="post">`

Comment: if form is post, make it post where you have put now, or change request as put. Then try and tell me.

Comment: Thanks, I had to change my `account_settings` to: `put 'join' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => :update_user_registration`